# Does creating an offline package for Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 include updates from Update 1?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, updates

I downloaded `VS2012.2.exe` and ran it via:

```
VS2012.2.exe /layout
```

to get an offline version of the installer.

Now I'm wondering whether this includes the whole set of updates ever since the RTM of Visual Studio 2012 or only those since Update 1.

The description [on the download page](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-visual-studio-2012-update) isn't exactly unambiguous:

> This update is the latest in a cumulative series of feature additions and bug fixes for Visual Studio 2012.

Cumulative makes sense, but the baseline isn't mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2797912

Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 is a cumulative release that includes the new features and fixes that were delivered in Visual Studio 2012 Update 1.

Comment: mentioned on the following page as well:
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/visual-studio-update

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in **cumulative** word.

From wikipedia description of "Service pack":

> A service pack can be "incremental", meaning it only contains the updates that were not present in the previous service packs, or it can be **cumulative**, which means it **includes the contents of all its predecessors**.

so, it is whole set of updates ever since the RTM of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and iso with the update created by microsoft, visit

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/05/03/announcing-availability-of-isos-for-visual-studio-updates.aspx

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=298533

Answer (score 0):

Update:
[Download Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 (Offline Installer / ISO)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=327544)